# JSF alternatives for $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Does `JSF` has any alternatives for `javascript`
`$(document).ready();`
?
I found `<h:outputScript/>`, but it seems that it not the same.

Comment: This question is strange. JSF is a HTML form application based MVC framework, not another JavaScript library. You can just keep using jQuery in JSF. Moreover, jQuery is already built into PrimeFaces (it's a jQuery based JSF component library, you know?). You'll likely have more chance in getting answers if you elaborately explain your actual http://xyproblem.info for which you incorrectly thought that the answer to this question would be the correct solution.

Comment: I mean that I want to simulate that behavior as when I use `$(document).ready();`. So for example init some custom javascript after page loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Primefaces and in your xhtml page, in the head, put this:

```
    <h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />
```

Comment: This is done automagically if the page contains jsf/PrimeFaces components